# Read CSV File into an ArrayList of Objects, no bug but failed to print out Object Information

Tags: java, csv, arraylist, deserialization

Here is my code for this specific part of reading the file. After I ran the project, no error jumped. But the console has no response at all. And no result is printed.

```
public class AdminMain {    

   static  ArrayList <Course> courses = new ArrayList<Course>();    
   private static final String COMMA_DELIMITER = ",";

   public static void main(String [] args) {
      BufferedReader br = null;

      try{
         br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("MyUniversityCourses.csv"));
         String line = " ";

         br.readLine();
          while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                String[] employeeDetails = line.split(COMMA_DELIMITER);      
                if(employeeDetails.length > 0 )
                {
                    //Save the employee details in Employee object
                    ArrayList<String>tempArray = new ArrayList<String> ();

                    Course temp = new Course(employeeDetails[0],employeeDetails[1],
                            Integer.parseInt(employeeDetails[2]),Integer.parseInt(employeeDetails[3]),
                            tempArray, employeeDetails[5],Integer.parseInt(employeeDetails[6]),employeeDetails[7]
                           );
                    courses.add(temp);  } }
     }
     catch(IOException ioe) {
          ioe.printStackTrace();
          return; 
        }
     System.out.println("Serialization success. ");

     for(Course a :courses) {
         System.out.print(a.getCourseName());
     }
     courses.forEach(System.out::println);
   }
```

Comment: Hello. Welcome to SO. Could you please provide a small of `MyUniversityCourses.csv` file ? So we can see what the file looks like. Also, have you considered using a tool/lib/framework to read CSV files ? Example : [BeanIO](http://beanio.org/)

Comment: Nothing at all or do you get the "Serialization success. " ?